# Adminer Docker for Oracle Database

Tags: oracle, docker, adminer

i need to connect adminer with oracle but its not supported in the official image. is there any adminer image for oracle connectivity? or if someone can guide me on how to install oci8 extension in current image.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following image in order to connect to oracle
https://hub.docker.com/r/soivangoi/nginx-php-adminer-oci8

for the server to use, please note that the syntax is the following :

host_ip:port/service_name (as described in .tnsnames.ora)

Answer (score 0):

Dockerfile:

```
FROM adminer:4.8.1


ENV LD_LIBRARY_PATH /usr/local/instantclient_21_1
ENV ORACLE_HOME /usr/local/instantclient_21_1

USER root
RUN apk update && apk upgrade --available \
 && apk add --no-cache bash autoconf build-base composer libaio libnsl libc6-compat busybox-extras

ADD tmp/. /tmp/.


RUN unzip -d /usr/local/ /tmp/instantclient-basic-linux.x64-21.1.0.0.0.zip
RUN unzip -d /usr/local/ /tmp/instantclient-sdk-linux.x64-21.1.0.0.0.zip
RUN unzip -d /usr/local/ /tmp/instantclient-sqlplus-linux.x64-21.1.0.0.0.zip

RUN ln -s /usr/lib/libnsl.so.2 /usr/lib/libnsl.so.1
RUN ln -s /lib/libc.so.6 /usr/lib/libresolv.so.2
RUN ln -s /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 /usr/lib/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
RUN pear upgrade --force && pecl upgrade

ADD tmp/instantclient.ini /etc/php.d/instantclient.ini

RUN docker-php-ext-configure oci8 --with-oci8=instantclient,$ORACLE_HOME
RUN docker-php-ext-install oci8
```

the oracle instant clien download URL:
`https://download.oracle.com/otn_software/linux/instantclient/211000/instantclient-basic-linux.x64-21.1.0.0.0.zip`
`https://download.oracle.com/otn_software/linux/instantclient/211000/instantclient-sqlplus-linux.x64-21.1.0.0.0.zip`
`https://download.oracle.com/otn_software/linux/instantclient/211000/instantclient-sdk-linux.x64-21.1.0.0.0.zip`

the `instantclient.ini` file content is `extension=oci8.so`

Answer (score 0):

Dockerfile:

```
FROM adminer:4.7.6

USER root
RUN apk update \
    && apk add --no-cache bash autoconf build-base composer libaio libnsl libc6-compat busybox-extras \
    && curl -o /tmp/instantclient.zip https://download.oracle.com/otn_software/linux/instantclient/211000/instantclient-basic-linux.x64-21.1.0.0.0.zip \
    && curl -o /tmp/sqlplus.zip https://download.oracle.com/otn_software/linux/instantclient/211000/instantclient-sqlplus-linux.x64-21.1.0.0.0.zip \
    && curl -o /tmp/sdk.zip https://download.oracle.com/otn_software/linux/instantclient/211000/instantclient-sdk-linux.x64-21.1.0.0.0.zip \
    && unzip -d /usr/local/ /tmp/instantclient.zip  && unzip -d /usr/local/ /tmp/sqlplus.zip \
    && unzip -d /usr/local/ /tmp/sdk.zip \
    && ln -s /usr/lib/libnsl.so.2 /usr/lib/libnsl.so.1 \
    && ln -s /lib/libc.so.6 /usr/lib/libresolv.so.2 \
    && ln -s /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 /usr/lib/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 \
    && pear upgrade --force  && pecl upgrade  && mkdir -p /etc/php.d/ \
    && echo "extension=oci8.so" > /etc/php.d/instantclient.ini \
    && docker-php-ext-configure oci8 --with-oci8=instantclient,/usr/local/instantclient_21_1 \
    && docker-php-ext-install oci8 \
    && rm -rf /tmp/*.zip /var/cache/apk/* /tmp/pear/

USER adminer
```